# RoR 3 - Registering domains for my clients

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am building a RoR3 site that generates a microsite for each client. At this moment they enter to their microsite using the url www.site.com/clientid , but I want to register their own domain programatically, so they will enter to www.clientid.com and they will be redirected to my server. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the client point the domain to your IP using the DNS management interface of the registrar. *(More technically this would result in the creation of an [A record](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/a.html) or an [AAAA record](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/aaaa.html) but this is not your concern)*.
Once the DNS is propagated, entering `www.clientid.com` in the browser will make a request to your server (your rails app). There you can selectively serve content based on the domain.

```
class ApplicationController
  before_filter do
    @current_account = Account.find_by_domain(request.domain)
  end
end
```

Comment: Is there anyway to make this without the client having to buy the domain? Maybe a godaddy api or something like that.

Comment: You could provide subdomains on your own domain in the form `clientid.yourdomain.com` using the same technique, and do `Account.find_by_subdomain(request.subdomain)` http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3 This means you need to set up your server accordingly for example in Apache `ServerAlias *.yourdomain.com`

Comment: Otherwise, if you want to descend straight from top level domain, you need to have the client buy the domain, or interface yourself with a registrar via API, acting as a third party.